# Sauce canning question - concerned that answer accepted as the way to do it when not intended as such

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Sauce canning question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81916/how-would-i-jar-a-sauce-for-keeping-at-room-temperature-without-adding-loads-of)

I am now concerned that an explanation about why an oven cannot be used for canning was misconstrued by the OP as a formula to do canning, especially when I quoted the arbitrary temperature mentioned in the question to illustrate my point.

Should I delete the answer and put it as a comment?

Comment: Can you throw the link to the Q&A into this question to make it easier for us to find?

Comment: I feel your concern here, especially since my (very tiny) research suggests that peanut sauce is a particularly tricky thing to can safely.

Comment: I've created a chat room about this. Anyone concerned, please go to [Peanut Sauce Canning Question Chattroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59473/peanut-sauce-canning-question)

Comment: OK, It's better now that it has been edited. @user110084 Thank you for trying to delete it, I didn't want to mod delete it. I wish I knew enough about canning to make it a really good answer.

Comment: @jolenalaska, thanks for all the help. I would have totally understood if it had been deleted. Very uncomfortable knowing an answer could have been misconstrued.