# What to do with dangerous wrong answer other than commenting?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Some of you might have seen this question coming. I am referring to the [Boil an egg in the microwave](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/boil-an-egg-in-the-microwave) shell-on question.

I have no issue with wrong answers except when it is one with potentially dangerous consequence and it is accepted as a good answer.

From a personal experience years ago, I am only too aware of the risk of getting seriously burnt and potentially blinded by what was offered as the answer. It can be done with plenty of care and precision about power setting in watts, and masses of water and egg, and absolutely not worth risking hospital treatment without these numbers and knowing how to underestimate the cooking time mathematically. Ideally, one should have a good calibration of power transfer from oven output to heating the food.

My concern is that some one could look at the accepted answer, skip everything else on the page, go out to attempt the vague settings and end up blinded as it almost happened to me.

This is similar to the problem I had with the [canning question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3385/sauce-canning-question-concerned-that-answer-accepted-as-the-way-to-do-it-when) where my answer as accepted could have been misinterpreted, except that this is more probable. Few people attempt canning, most of us had thought about cooking eggs in a microwave.

Is there any way to defuse this risk from a bad but accepted answer?

Comment: Looks like the OP has come back... I've advised them to consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you @Catija. Appreciate your intervention. I read OP's comment, glad they did not suffer any injury.